# Как получить полный URL с открытием страницы и подгружаемой информацией

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii2, url

Коллеги, день добрый.

Есть немного странная задача (больше даже из интереса). Есть сайт, построенный на фреймворке yii2.

Представим ситуацию. Есть статическое меню, из него переходим на страницу `A`, разделенную на 2 части:

1. со списком с элементами.
2. сюда подгружается информация исходя из того на какой элемент нажмешь.

Как можно получить ссылку, благодаря которой я сразу смогу перейти к странице `A` c конкретно выбранным элементом и подгруженной информацией в блоке 2?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от реализации меню и догрузки на клиенте. Можно использовать ["якорные ссылки"](http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/yakorya) , и если есть возможность рендерить на сервере контент сразу всех пунктов меню, тогда клиентские скрипты даже не потребуются и достаточно сверстать меню с `display: fixed`, а контент соответственно авто-скроллится до якорной ссылки. Полное решение с догрузкой предполагает анализ объекта `window.location` с последующей активизацией AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно только если на клиенте анализировать URL или какие либо иные подсказки переданные с сервера, после чего аяксом загружать недостающую часть страницы. Это если вы хотите сохранить текущую логику загрузки. Можно сделать так чтобы сервер целиком отправлял обе части. PS Ужасно раздражают такие подгружаемые блоки текста в три строчки - руки бы поотрывал.